# Avoid enter key press in shell script

Tags: visual-studio-code, sh

I have a shell script as shown below.

```
trap_ctrlc ()
{
    echo ""
    echo "Trying to terminate docker container gracefully, please wait."
    docker-compose stop
    echo "Press Enter."
    exit
}
trap "trap_ctrlc" INT

docker-compose up -d

some-code-to-run-app.js
```

My Goal here is to run the application after starting docker container. But if user clicks **ctrl+c**, then this script should trap that signal and it should kill the container and exit. Everything is working fine, except when user clicks **ctrl+c**, it is stopping the container but it is not exiting instead it is waiting for a enter key press to exit. So, i didn't understand what is the issue with this.

I run this script with below command

```
sh start.sh
```

[image: Please see in below image]

Answer (score 0):

Trap catches the specified signal, and *instead of* doing what it would normally do, it will run the command you specify.

In this case, it will run your `trap_ctrlc` function *instead of* exiting.

You just need to add an `exit`, where you currently have `echo "Press Enter."`.

Comment: Hi, I tried that. It did not work. Still the same issue.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: Hi am using bash